# Problemas con un Spinner en uno de mis fragments

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy intentando hacer un spinner en un fragment y no soy capaz de hacerlo funcionar, este es el error que me da:

> Android resource linking failed
> com.example.login.app-mergeDebugResources-38:/layout/fragment_gallery.xml:53: error: 'spinner_intervenciones' is incompatible with attribute entries (attr) reference.
> error: failed linking file resources.

A continuación el código que tengo con respecto a este spinner.

Este es el código en strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="spinner_intervenciones">
    <item>Caldera estropeada</item>
    <item>Goteras</item>
    <item>Ventana rota</item>
    <item>Puerta atascada</item>
    <item>Encuentro con sugi</item>
    <item>Electrodomesticos estropeados</item>
    <item>Copia del contrato perdida</item>
    <item>Cambiar una bombilla</item>
    <item>Romper un bombillo</item>
    <item>Problemas con la electricidad</item>
    <item>Problemas con el agua</item>
</string-array>
```

Este es el codigo de mi layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_intervenciones"
    android:layout_width="215dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_intervenciones"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
```

Y por ultimo este es el fragment principal:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    GalleryViewModel galleryViewModelBtn=
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    GalleryViewModel galleryViewModelEdit=
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    GalleryViewModel galleryViewModelTxtView=
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    GalleryViewModel galleryViewModelSpinner=
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

    binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    final TextView textView = binding.textGallery;
    final EditText edittext = binding.editIntervenciones;
    final Button enviarIntervencion = binding.btnAdelante;
    final Spinner spin = binding.spinnerIntervenciones;
    galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
    galleryViewModelEdit.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
    galleryViewModelBtn.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),textView::setText);
    galleryViewModelSpinner.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),textView::setText);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
    enviarIntervencion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
```

}

Si alguien pudiera echarle un vistazo a ver si encuentra el fallo lo agradeceria, ya que yo no lo estoy consiguiendo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cual es la linea 53 de fragment_gallery.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que indica el error:

> error: 'spinner_intervenciones' is incompatible with attribute entries
> (attr) reference.

es que el valor del atributo `android:entries` es incorrecto, te sugiero inicialmente limpiar y reconstruir tu proyecto.

Al parecer la referencia del Array para ser cargado en el `Spinner` es correcta, debes asegurar que tu array dentro del archivo `strings.xml` este contenido dentro de `<resources>` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <string-array name="spinner_intervenciones">
    <item>Caldera estropeada</item>
    <item>Goteras</item>
    <item>Ventana rota</item>
    <item>Puerta atascada</item>
    <item>Encuentro con sugi</item>
    <item>Electrodomesticos estropeados</item>
    <item>Copia del contrato perdida</item>
    <item>Cambiar una bombilla</item>
    <item>Romper un bombillo</item>
    <item>Problemas con la electricidad</item>
    <item>Problemas con el agua</item>
   </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Tienes razon, gracias, el problema era donde tenia colocada mi array

Comment: Excelente @jose7sk8 , recuerda que si la respuesta ayudo a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, puedes marcarla como solución , revisa [tour], saludos.